# SQL NULL in DDL (Data Definition Language)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I imported datas from a .txt file to my database via postgresql. 
The problem is, some columns of some movies are empty. E.g there is no rating for the film "abcd" , when importing via `COPY` postgresql throws an error "no data in this column". How can I catch this error in my `CREATE TABLE` order. I tried it with "NULL", but it does not work either.

```
  CREATE TABLE movies
 (
 imdib  varchar NOT NULL,
  name varchar NOT NULL,
  year integer NULL,
  rating float NULL ,
  votes integer NULL ,
  runtime varchar NULL ,
  directors varchar NULL ,
  actors varchar NULL ,
  genres varchar NULL
  );

COPY movies from 'C:\Users\Max\Desktop\imdb_top100t.txt' DELIMITER E'\t' ;
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
ERROR:  missing data for column „year“
CONTEXT:  COPY movies,  Line 3060: „tt0283003   “
********** Error **********
ERROR:  missing data for column „year“
SQL Status:22P04
Context: COPY movies, Line 3060: „tt0283003 “
```

**EDIT: This is on line 3060**

> tt0081590   Sällskapsresan eller Finns det svenskt kaffe på grisfesten  1980    7.3 4477    107 mins.   Lasse Ã
>   berg|Peter Hald Lasse Ã
>   berg|Lottie Ejebrant|Jon Skolmen    Comedy

**EDIT 2: I think this is the problem "Ã" postgresql can not recognize this letter **

Comment: And what exactly **is** on line 3060 ?

Comment: this: 
tt0081590 Sällskapsresan eller Finns det svenskt kaffe på grisfesten 1980 7.3 4477 107 mins. Lasse Ã
berg|Peter Hald Lasse Ã
berg|Lottie Ejebrant|Jon Skolmen Comedy

Comment: And the thin bars are supposed to be tab characters?

Comment: COPY is complaining about the line starting with `tt0283003`, not `tt0081590`.

Answer (score 0):

NULL in the default COPY format is expressed as `\N` as can be seen with:

```
 copy (select null) to stdout;
```

Result:

```
\N
```

But if you're COPY'ing FROM a file that has not been exported by Postgres COPY TO that file, there's no reason that it would use the postgres format with its backslash escape sequences.

Generally, it's the CSV format that is used for tabular-style data, and that needs to be turned on explicitly as an option to COPY, as in:

```
COPY tablename FROM 'filename.txt' (DELIMITER E'\t', FORMAT CSV, NULL '');
```

NULL can be distinguished from empty strings if necessary by using the `FORCE_QUOTE` and `FORCE_NOT_NULL` options.

Answer (score 0):

This is on line 3060:

> tt0081590   Sällskapsresan eller Finns det svenskt kaffe på grisfesten  1980    7.3 4477    107 mins.   Lasse Ã
>   berg|Peter Hald Lasse Ã
>   berg|Lottie Ejebrant|Jon Skolmen    Comedy